# check unrepeated random number

Tags: java, loops, random

I have a method that return a number:

```
  public String getNum()
   {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(1000) + "";
   }
```

And I have this method that stores an object

```
public void store(User user)
{
  String str = getNum();
  user.setIdCode(str);
  for (User users: userList)
  { 
    if(users.getId() == user.getId())
{
user.setIdCode(getNum);
}

  }

}
```

if Id is excited than re-set the id. This is for sure checks if the id exists the first time but how about the second time that id is set. there would be a possibility of repeating the same number. At the same time we cant go in infinite loop.

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @stdunbar I think OP is not asking about the why it gets wrong, he is more concerned about what if duplicate id is given to another user.

Comment: Hey @MajdaElferjani do mark the answer as correct by clicking the V type tick mark looking button next to the answer, this helps future readers of the question on SO and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is add a few random numbers in a `Set` and then use them separately whenever you want.

What I mean by it is that if you're trying to get a random number every time, you can just store some random numbers at once and then retrieve them one by one when you need them.

In code, put this in some method called `storeRandomNumbers()` and call it in the beginning of your program. Also, declare the `Set` as a global variable.

You can also make a separate variable to keep track of how many random numbers have been used up and use it to retrieve the next random number from the `Set`.

The code would look something like this (makes changes according to your needs):

```java
Random rand = new Random();
Set<Integer> uniqueRandoms = new HashSet<>();
while (uniqueRandoms.size()<10){
    uniqueRandoms.add(rand.nextInt(11));
}
for (Integer i : uniqueRandoms){
    // System.out.print(i+" ");
    // retrieve them from here and use them whenever you want
}
```

**Edit:**
Yes as @Andreas gave the link to suggest, you don't compare Strings with `==`, rather you use the `equals()` method.